# Why is node stuck in a loop after loading a file requiring Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am very new to coding and I am taking Colt Steele's web development bootcamp course online. The course has been great so far, however I think some portions are outdated.

When I am in node and enter .load .index.js, the terminal gets stuck in some sort of loop and continuously prints "const mongoose = require('mongoose')." I pasted my code below if that helps. Please let me know if you think you know my error, thank you!

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/movieApp')
.then(() => {
    console.log("connection open!");
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log("oh no, error!");
    console.log(err);
})

const movieSchema = new mongoose.Schema( {
    title: String,
    year: Number,
    score: Number,
    rating: String
})

const Movie = mongoose.model('Movie', movieSchema);
```

I tried resaving the file, and attempting different ways to connect to the database. However, each time I still got the same loop. I am hoping for node to load my code and enter the REPL.

Comment: How do you run this code?

Comment: What happens if you run it with ```node index.js``` from your terminal?

Comment: @Konrad I run the code by typing .load index.js when I am in node. I am hoping to enter the REPL in node. When I just run it by typing node index.js in bash it works fine. But that won't allow me to enter the REPL

Comment: @aurelienrichard It works completely fine when I do it that way. But I am trying to follow along with the videos in this course and the entire mongoose section is done within node by typing .load index.js. That way he enters the REPL and is able to start examining the code. I am still pretty new to this so my apologies if I am using incorrect terminology.

Comment: It works fine for me. What is your node version?

Comment: @Konrad V18.13.0. Would that be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in the question forum in the course I am taking. The TA posted this:

UPDATE (SOLUTION):

This seems like a bug with the newest versions of node with how it works with mongoose.

Instead of using .load index.js inside of the node shell, use the command
node -i -e "$(< index.js)" in the system terminal (outside of the node shell, just be sure that you first change directories into the folder containing the index.js file) — this will load the file and start the node with this one command instead, and then it should work.